get calender from another user - PowerAutomate
I have an instant cloud flow that checks whether vacation requests have been created in the SharePoint list. If so, the flow should automatically create a calendar entry in the respective person's Outlook. How can I input that into the flow? Thank you very much for the support.
//  I've already got a working flow, but for only myself. If other users also make entries, it should also be saved in their calendar. What can I do to make the calendar dynamic?
can I work with variables like that: @{body('Get_signed-in_user_profile')?['userPrincipalName']} (is invalid)

You need to change the Run as User setting of the flow. Change the Outlook connector to Provide by run only user

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have done this as a first step:
{
   "type":"OpenApiConnection",
   "inputs":{
      "parameters":{
         "id":"@triggerBody()?['Author']?['Email']"
      },
      "host":{
         "apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365users",
         "connection":"shared_office365users",
         "operationId":"UserProfile_V2"
      }
   },
   "runAfter":{
      "Compose_1":[
         "Succeeded"
      ]
   }
}

and this as a next step:
{
   "type":"OpenApiConnection",
   "inputs":{
      "parameters":{
         "table":"@outputs('Get_user_profile')?['body/calendarId']",
         "item/subject":"Ferien",
         "item/start":"@outputs('Format_StartDate')",
         "item/end":"@outputs('Compose_1')",
         "item/timeZone":"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
      },
      "host":{
         "apiId":"/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_office365",
         "connection":"shared_office365",
         "operationId":"V4CalendarPostItem"
      }
   },
   "runAfter":{
      "Get_user_profile":[
         "Succeeded"
      ]
   }
}

